# Unable to delete Microsoft Azure Service Bus Namespace

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I have two junk Service Bus Namespaces that are cluttering up my screen that I created on my Free Trial account and are now in a Disabled state. Now that I have a paid account I cannot delete them, and cannot figure out why.

On the dashboard I select the item, click the Delete icon, and see the pop-up. I type in exactly as it says to confirm namespace name but cannot click the check-mark for all it says is "Failed to retrieve namespace details."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this happen before.  The only way you'll get this resolve is via Microsoft (Azure) Support.  See http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/faq/

Comment: Thanks Brendan, sucks though...I hope they classify this as a "billing" support ticket.

Comment: If I recall correctly, I was able to get it pushed through under billing support. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

You can delete service bus namespaces from the management portal:

https://manage.windowsazure.com

You have to go to the 'ALL ITEMS' tab and then select the service bus namespace (don't click on the name column) from there and you should see a [delete option at the bottom of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kf2G2.png)

Comment: For others, deleting the namespace from the new portal (portal.azure.com) now seems to work. If not, you can use this